# TableView in XIB file causing errors

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I am trying to add a tableView in an XIB file but am getting this error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.` . I have never used XIB files before so I'm not sure what the issue could be

This is how I load the XIB:

```
let scoresVC = UIViewController(nibName: "LiveScoresViewController", bundle: nil)
navigationController?.pushViewController(scoresVC, animated: true)

class LiveScoresViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LiveScoreCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LiveScoreCell")
    }
}
```

[image: XIB set up]

Comment: How are you loading the xib? Are you creating an instance of `LiveScoresViewController`? If so, show us that code.

Comment: I just added it to the question, it was also loading fine before I added the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is `let scoresVC = UIViewController(nibName: "LiveScoresViewController", bundle: nil)` this line . You need to change with like this :

```
let scoresVC = LiveScoresViewController(nibName: "LiveScoresViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a plain `UIViewController` and telling it to load its view from `LiveScoresViewController.xib`. You need to create an instance of `LiveScoresViewController`. This should work:

```
let scoresVC = LiveScoresViewController()
```

The object will use its own class name to find the xib.